# Android - Adding XML data into an arraylist

Tags: java, android, xml, arraylist

Given an xml file like this one:

```
<Providers>
  <CarDealer name="BEFORWARD" id="1">
    <CarMake name="Toyota" id="20" stype="se01">
      <CarModel name="Belta" id="21"/>
      <CarModel name="RunX" id="22"/>
      <CarModel name="Corolla" id="23"/>
    </CarMake>
    <CarMake name="Nissan" id="30" stype="se02">
      <CarModel name="Murano" id="31"/>
      <CarModel name="Pathfinder" id="32"/>
      <CarModel name="Navara" id="33"/>
    </CarMake>
  </CarDealer>
```

How would I go about storing the name, id and stype (node children) from this xml into an arraylist? Here is what I tried to do using the `XMLPullParser` of my handler class:

```
public class SAXXMLHandler extends DefaultHandler {
private List<CarMake> carMaker;
private String tempVal;
// to maintain context
private CarMake carmake;

public SAXXMLHandler() {

carMaker = new ArrayList<CarMake>();
}

public List<CarMake> getCarMake() {

return carMaker;
}

// Event Handlers
public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName,
                     Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {
// reset
tempVal = "";
if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("CarMake")) {
    // create a new instance of CarMake
    carmake = new CarMake();
    carmake.setName(attributes.getValue("name"));
  }
}

public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length)
    throws SAXException {
tempVal = new String(ch, start, length);
}

public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName)
    throws SAXException {

if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("CarMake")) {
    // add it to the list
    carMaker.add(carmake);
} else if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("CarModel")) {
    carmake.setCarModel(tempVal);
  }
 }
 }
```

My handler class is only getting the name attribute. How would I go about getting everything and store in an arraylist? Please note, am still learning Android programing.

Comment: [This article](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/xml.html) describes exactly what you want to do, parsing the XML and making an ArrayList.

Comment: thanks @NicolasMaltais let check it out